# Two identical arrays except one element - Logarithmic algorithm to find that element

Tags: algorithm

I ran into an exercise and cannot come up with a solution.

The question is as follows: 
A Computer Science student was working on a PowerPoint presentation. 
Unfortunately, it turned out to him that he does not remember which version is the updated one (he had two versions of the presentation). 
Both presentation are the same except one slide that can be found only in the **first** presentation. 
The student wants to find the slide that is only in the first presentation (it is not necessarily the first or the last slide). 
We will mark the number of slides in the second presentation as **n**. 
Suggest an algorithm to find the missing slide in the second presentation.

**Note:** I should not any sorting and the algorithm should be logarithmic (probably O(log n)).

Comment: If he just wants to know which presentation is which, he can look at which one is longer. Finding the missing slide is overkill.

Comment: Hint: binary search. What happens to all the elements after the inserted element?

Comment: @user2357112 "Suggest an algorithm to find the missing slide"

Comment: @Dukeling, I thought about binary search but I don't know what slide to actually look for so I'm not sure how to formulate a solution here.

Comment: Are all slides unique within one presentation?

Answer (score 2):

aAssuming that all slides are unique within one presenantation, you can use binary search. The idea is that all slides that go after the inserted one (including it) are different from  slide in the other presentation at the corresponding position. Conversely, all slides before the inserted one are equal in both presentations. Thus, you can use binary search to find the smallest `i` such that `slides1[i] != slides2[i]`.

If the slides are not unique, I don't think you can do anything better than a linear search (consider the case `1, 1, 1, .. 2, 1, 1, 1`; `1, 1, 1, ..., 1`, where `2` is the new slide and all other slides are the same. You can't get any useful information unless you check the position where the slide `2` is located).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the binary search idea, without giving away the solution.
So, lets examine the slides at the center of the presentations (the values at the same index). If the inserted file is before this point, what would we expect when we compare these slides?
If the inserted slide is after this point, what would we expect when we compare these slides?
If the inserted slide is one of these slides, what would we expect, and how would it be different than the previous cases?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Binary Search algorithm...

- Look at the middle slide of the smaller of the two presentations. Its index would be i = (start + end) / 2. Since the slide numbers start from 1, the first value for start would be 1 and the first value for end would be n.
- If i<sup>th</sup> slide in the bigger presentation is the same as the i<sup>th</sup> slide in the smaller presentation, it means you do the same process with start updated to i + 1 because the missing slide is in the slides after this middle slide.
- Else do the same process with end updated to i - 1 because missing slide is somewhere before this middle index slide.